# get all expiry_date that have expired in the past 12 days

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date = DATE(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 8 DAY))
```

How can I modify this query to that I can get a list of `exipry_date` that has expired within the last 12 days?

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `exipry_date` BETWEEN DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -12 DAY) AND NOW();
```